# Faster Harmonic Number?

Tags: c++, performance, numbers

I'm a beginner in programming. I am trying to make a program that given two numbers it substracts one harmonic from the other. (Input: n, m / Output: Hn-Hm)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
double n1, n2, h1 = 0, h2 = 0, i;       // n = number, h = harmonic
cin >> n1 >> n2;

    if (n1 == 0) {
        h1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 1; i <= n1; i++) { 
            h1 += 1 / i;
            if (i <= n2) {
                h2 += 1 / i;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << h1 - h2 << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The program gives correct results but I'm using a website of my university and it says that the program is slow. I've tried to make it faster but I can't figure out how. 
Thanks.

Comment: Add a description of what is harmonic, or at least a reference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: That `system("pause")` will make your program *infinitely* slow. It stops the program form doing anything more until a key is pressed. If a keypress is not coming it will wait forever.

Comment: One thing I would do is get rid of the branch in the loop.

Comment: There's no need to calculate both harmonic numbers. The first n terms of both series will cancel each other out when you subtract them, so you only need to calculate the terms for the residue of the higher series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the full harmonic numbers. Assuming `n1 < n2`, the two series will be:

```
H(n1) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n1
H(n2) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n1 + 1/(n1+1) + 1(n1+2) + ... + 1/n2
```

So when you subtract `H(n2) - H(n1)`, the first `n1` terms in the two series cancel each other out, so

```
H(n2) - H(n1) = 1/(n1+1) + 1(n1+2) + ... + 1/n2
```

If `n1 > n2` the result is the negative of this.

```
double result = 0, mult = 1;
if (n1 > n2) {
    double temp = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = temp;
    mult = -1;
}
for (double denom = n1+1; denom <= n2; denom++) {
    result += 1/denom;
}
result *= mult; // Flip the sign if we swapped n1 and n2
cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << result << endl;
```